# Equivalent In Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

Im Trying to get the Visual Basic. Net Equivalent of this function in c#

```
public bool IsBomb { get { return number == -1; } }
```

I Tried the Get Function but im not sure how to implement it in vb.net

Comment: `Get` is not a function, its a Property accessor

Answer (score 3):

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property isBomb as Boolean
    Get
         return (number = -1)
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Sorry about editing your comment, it was a mistake.  I meant to edit mine, but they looked so similar I clicked the wrong one. Changes have been rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

Read this document on MSDN about implementing properties in VB.NET.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3dtbky.aspx

Comment: A link to the documentation is great, but this answer will be useless the next time MS changes their web site's file names.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public ReadOnly Property IsBomb As Boolean
    Get
        Return CBool(number = 1)
    End Get
End Property
```

For future reference, there is a great site for converting C# to vb.net and vice-versa.
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: `CBool` isn't strictly necessary, but I prefer it for clarity when reading it later.